# Electron main process not loading other files once compiled with Electron Builder

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

- In dev, everything works fine however once I compile my files using Electron Builder the main process no longer loads the `index.html` file and consequently the `renderer.js` file.
- I have tried using a combination of `__dirname` as well as relative/absolute file paths but I cannot get it to work
- I have created a [minimal reproducible example](https://github.com/alexandermckay/electron-builder-error/tree/master) to further explain my point.

## Steps to reproduce

- `git clone`
- `cd electron-builder-error`
- `yarn install`
- `yarn webpack`
- `yarn dev (works fine)`
- `yarn prod (builds fine)`
- `Run the installer`
- `Open the program and notice that everything is blank`

Answer (score 0):

At your `main.js`

```
function createWindow(): void {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      webSecurity: false
    }
  })

  win.loadFile(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'? './index.html' : './compiled/index.html' )
}
```

And you should pass the `NODE_ENV` variable at your webpapck configuration. Normally, this is set as `production` So when you run as dev without setting `NODE_ENV` then it won't work.

---